# Is the re-use of the image on these posts appropriate?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, duplicate-answers, abuse, specific-user

Here are the posts:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/74637625/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/74615350/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/74490727/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/74450165/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/74615758/

Here's a [deleted one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74613673/how-to-deploy-keras-tcn-model-to-vue-app-with-tensorflow-js/74616244#74616244) as well. I got some kind of response regarding the image there, but I couldn't really understand what it was trying to say.

I'm mostly asking about the Flappy Bird image, but the code blocks that supposedly have to do with the image are also the same on all those posts. The other parts of the answers, however, seem to be different in content, so they're not self-duplicate answers.

As far as I can understand these answers, the images don't seem to have any relevance to the questions or rest of the answer at all and come across as noise. I've tried editing them out, but some of them ended up getting rolled back or re-added.

I don't want to engage in a rollback war, but I also want to keep the site clean.

Was it appropriate to edit these out in the first place? Is this something I should flag now?

Comment: I don't know what the images are adding to those answers, if I am honest.

Comment: They're adding color, and nostalgia, duh

Comment: I'm more confused by the user's use of blockquotes; they arent referencing anything and they aren't quoting something else on the post, so what are they quoting? What ever they *are* quoting it's uncited, which is against the referencing guidelines (read rules).

Comment: Generally it should be ok as long as those are related to the answer. In these specific cases: I can't tell. You've also wrote OP in one of those answers, but I would suggest to explicitly ask them why they added that image in answers where you think they don't belong to. And if that code snippet can be used to render pictures (I can't tell, don't know Python), then I think its fine to have an example image in the answer. But it could be downsized a bit to take less space.

Comment: @Larnu Most likely just a poor attempt to increase visibility of text between code blocks. Unnecessary, yes, but I've seen several relatively new users do that :/.

Comment: Yeah, "new" users I see do it, @Tom , but that user has been around long enough to know what correct and incorrect use of blockquotes are.

Comment: @Tom I got an "explanation" on a now [deleted post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74613673/how-to-deploy-keras-tcn-model-to-vue-app-with-tensorflow-js/74616244#74616244). I could not understand the response I got.

Comment: I feel like what you are really wanting to ask here is not just is it "ok" to reuse th images, but if it's ok to keep reusing content from their posts; it's not just the images they are reusing here but the code as well.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance I don't unterstand it either. I guess he didn't understand the question and tried to answer it more generally? It's weird.

Comment: @Larnu Hm... yes, I am concerned about that too. Can I include that and still keep this discussion reasonably scoped? Maybe if I changed the title from "images" to "content"?

Comment: It seems like they edited the image back into [these two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74637625/) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74450165/) - revisions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74637625/5) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74450165/3). I've re-edited them out, but it might be better to just watch the linked posts for a few days.

Comment: Re the first reference: On Stack Exchange, there seems to be a new trend of misspellings by adding the letter "e" (or doubling it) to words (not only on Stack Overflow). Registered very recently: *"[mostely](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=mostely)"*, *"[unite](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=unite)"*, *"[greately](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=greately)"*, *"[moree](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=moree)"*, *"[refreesh](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=refreesh)"*,

Comment: cont' - *"[aree](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=aree)"*, and *"[secrete](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=secrete)"*. It can't all be attributed to broken keyboards (e.g., the three double 'e's) or typos ('e' and 't' are separated by one key ('r')). And most likely not by chance (there are too many of them). E.g., was there some kind of operating system or web browser update that could explain this, e.g. in Android? And/or introduction of some AI thing with unspecified IQ? E.g., a new kind of autocorrect (that doesn't use an actual dictionary)?

Comment: Hi, I will read all comments later but it is the implementation of the game in the picture I added to explain the codes I used to add it as GIF but they keep deleting it.  The variables in the matrixes are game variances and select of max() or min() mapped to functions. > If you want to see it i also added it into my Facebook album AI.

Comment: @JirayuKaewprateep You're only now trying to explain what it does? And they still doesn't look relevant to the questions asked. On [this one especially](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74450165/), you give an explanation then immediately contradict yourself with that code sample.

Comment: And wait a minute... the question was never what the code *does*, it's *why* it's relevant to *all* those posts. That's still unexplained.

Comment: @JirayuKaewprateep If content you are providing in answers is continually edited out it is a strong signal it's very likely irrelevant and unwanted.

Comment: The images are the least of the problem. I think it is a severe case. A possible explanation is a toxic combination of using [machine translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translate) (see e.g. comments to TylerH's answer), leaving out punctuation inbetween sentences, leaving out articles, etc. I think there is very little value in keeping any of those Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: cont' - Another explanation (less likely) is some kind of bot or script that generates answers (based on the user's own [language model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model#Notable_language_models)?) - using Stack Overflow for test runs? Usually only machine translation is capable of producing that level of incomprehensible text. Even the worst broken English is way better.

Comment: @PeterMortensen After studying the situation a bit more, I think the motivation behind these answers is (poorly executed) self-promotion now. The format of the answers (and others) generally follow the format of 1. Comment on question 2. Oh, BTW here's some out-of-context code I wrote from some TF/ML-related project I made. Why the user insists on them being relevant despite all evidence to the contrary is still a mystery, and there are only so many ways I can say, "Please improve your English," when I keep getting ignored. So, yes, I also think there's little/no value in keeping these.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts @GeneralGrievance.. I am glad someone finally reported this.

Comment: Holy... This isn't the first time he's tried this kind of thing: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70861679/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71230496/), and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71160408/). Now I'm almost positive about my clickbait/self-promotion theory.

Comment: @General Grievance: Fortunately, it stopped. But there are still [250 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7848579/jirayu-kaewprateep?tab=answers&sort=newest&page=5) with close-to-incomprehensible text. It was also [noted in May 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72105446/what-is-the-prediction-value-of-this-lstm-neural-network/72106710#comment127424442_72106710).

Comment: [Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72074745/error-while-tensorflow-import-using-the-command-from-tensorflow-keras-models-im/72075093#comment127351180_72075093).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yeah, I know. At around this time last year, he was suspended last year for plagiarism (and I caught two sock accounts). I took that time to clean up the the worst of the image use so they weren't so rudely taking up space for other answers. I'm not sure what to do about the incomprehensible English, but at this point, it's no longer an active and persistent issue, so I've opted to just quietly monitor he account.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are several problems with this user's posts.

First, yes the Flappy Bird image is totally irrelevant here and should be removed. If the questions or answers were somehow related to Flappy Bird, making the image relevant, then it arguably would be OK to include it, even multiple times.

Second, the user is misusing quote formatting for non-quoted content; using it for what I assume is emphasis.

It is appropriate to fix these things when you see them. If you see a user consistently including this kind of stuff in answers, or if you see them rollback your edits, flag for a moderator to take a look and send a message to the user, if need be.

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the (mis)use of blockquotes on the linked answers and left a comment for the OP explaining why on one of them. I haven't checked the rest of their content, but I suspect it's rife with the (mis)use.

Comment: It explained the application and weights matrix on communication devices as you understand robots, and removed them some users may not understand that we sent only as a matrix to target devices and it ran function mapping.

Comment: I changed to another example simply word to sequence auto-encoder but it will look more closed to password codes breaker please take consider.

Comment: @JirayuKaewprateep Again... I'm having immense difficulty understanding your comments. There are a large number of basic grammar and syntax issues that are present in your sentences that are making this extremely difficult. From what I can gather you are just giving an example just to say, "By the way, this is applicable to robots," or something else the OPs aren't asking about.

Comment: I can't tell at all what Jirayu's comments mean but the edits on the main post of the first answer above make it seem like the flappy bird image is relevant to the code of Jirayu's answer... which means Jirayu's answer _itself_ is irrelevant to the question that was asked (Tensorflow is a machine learning language, not a game programming language), so I have voted to simply delete the answer.

Comment: I explained as feedback system, if not I need to example as a  text coder that will look like a codes breaker. Some examples I do as image classification or derivative product or series that is harder to understand.

Comment: @JirayuKaewprateep Unfortunately I think there's too much of a language barrier here; I would recommend finding someone who is fluent in English and whatever your native language is try and assist you before participating further. Otherwise we just won't be able to understand you.

Comment: I don't think it is a languages barriers but my example is valid when it shown as the GIF image below and I can explain about sciences I applied for the results.

Comment: @JirayuKaewprateep Do you understand what "language barrier" means?

Comment: I replied to question again they removed part they need and you keep telling it make none sense to the question when removed the examples.

Comment: To the question, it does answer of implementing of weights matrix and distribution to create feedbacks system. That is right to the question and implementation, you removed the GIF image now can do explain about distribution to anyone understand with this simple line of code temp = np.asarray(temp) * np.asarray([ coefficient_0, coefficient_1, coefficient_2, coefficient_3, coefficient_4, coefficient_5, coefficient_6, coefficient_7, coefficient_8, coefficient_9 ]) and perform actions { UP, HOLD } !?